# Obter caminho de arquivos válidos com expressão regular

Tags: c#, regex

**Contexto:**

Estou monitorando ações de exclusão e inclusão de arquivos em uma pasta através da Classe [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) com o intuito de registrar um Log das ações realizas nela.

**Problema:**

Esta pasta contém diversos arquivos e subpastas que não me interessam monitorar, portanto antes de gravar o Log, preciso verificar se a ação realizada, foi realizada em um arquivo relevante para ser salva.

**Premissas da expressão**

- O arquivo deve estar no 2 nível.
  Ex.: Pasta1\Pasta2\Arquivo.qlqCoisa
- O arquivo deve pertencer a pasta `Rem` (ser filho direto)
  Ex.: Pasta1\Rem\Arquivo.qlqCoisa

**Exemplos de expressões válidas e inválidas:**

```
"Cliente1\\Rem\\COB0111111.REM.txt"          //Nome Valido
"Cliente1\\Rem\\23123123.REM.txt"            //Nome Valido
"Cliente1\\OK\\COB02222222.REM.txt"          //Invalido
"Cliente1\\Ret\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"       //Invalido
"COB0613062019.REM.txt"                      //Invalido
"Cliente2\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"            //Invalido
"Cliente2\\Rem\\COB0633333.REM.txt"          //Nome Valido
"Cliente2\\Rem\\pasta2\\COB02123123.REM.txt" //Invalido
"Cliente2\\Bla\\Rem\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"  //Invalido
"Cliente1\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"            //Invalido
"Rem\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"                 //Invalido
"Rem" //Invalido
"Cliente3" //Invalido
```

Realizei essa verificação com `.split` e condicionais, porém gostaria de realizá-la REGEX.

**MCVE** (Exemplo de solução sem expressão regular):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> nomes = new List<string>();
            List<String> nomesValidos = new List<string>();

            nomes.Add("Cliente1\\Rem\\COB0111111.REM.txt"); //Nome Valido
            nomes.Add("Cliente1\\Rem\\23123123.REM.txt"); //Nome Valido
            nomes.Add("Cliente1\\OK\\COB02222222.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Cliente1\\Ret\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("COB0613062019.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Cliente2\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Cliente2\\Rem\\COB0633333.REM.txt"); //Nome Valido
            nomes.Add("Cliente2\\Rem\\pasta2\\COB02123123.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Cliente2\\Bla\\Rem\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Cliente1\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Rem\\COB0613062019.REM.txt"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Rem"); //Invalido
            nomes.Add("Cliente3"); //Invalido

            foreach (string nome in nomes) {
                var teste = nome.Split("\\");
                if (teste.Length == 3) { //Garanto que estará no 2 nível
                    if (teste[1].ToUpper() == "REM") { //Garanto que o pai direto do arquivo é REM
                        nomesValidos.Add(nome);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (string nome in nomesValidos) {
                Console.WriteLine(nome);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Tentei fazer algumas expressões no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LfBxSG/2), mas não cheguei muito perto do que gostaria.

Comment: O MCVE ficou melhor do que com RegEx.

Comment: @Bacco exceto a parte de dar `.Add()`pra cada elemento pra criar a lista inicial, e o `ToUpper()` e o jeito de escrever a barra invertida na *string*.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: já considerou usar o filter nativo?  (2o parametro) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileSystemWatcher__ctor_System_String_System_String_

Comment: @Maniero Coloquei as string de exemplo exatamente como file watcher retorna no `EventArgs`, a minha dúvida era de como construir uma RegEx que fizesse o mesmo que esse MCVE. @Bacco não sabia que o parametro filter aceitava pattern, lerei o link que você mandou.

Comment: Acho que fez o bom e agora procurando piorar. RegEx sempre é pior em tudo o que pode analisar.

Comment: @Maniero você diz no sentido de performance?

Comment: Eu disse em todos. Eu não respondi porque a pergunta pede claramente pra fazer algo pior, mas eu pelo menos faria esse mesmo código de forma mais simples e correto:https://dotnetfiddle.net/qLM6Mg.

Comment: Eu não tinha ciência de que RegEx é sempre pior, de que deveria ser usada só em ultimo caso, se não eu teria mantido a solução inicial.

Comment: Ainda mais agora que eu te dei a que não faz alocações desnecessárias que é o que deixava lento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua solução com `Split` já ficou bem simples e não sei se realmente precisa de regex, mas de qualquer forma, uma solução seria:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[^\\]+\\Rem\\[^\\]+$");
if (regex.IsMatch(@"Cliente1\Rem\COB0111111.REM.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Válido");    
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inválido");  
}
```

No caso, estou assumindo que os nomes dos arquivos e diretórios são "qualquer coisa que não seja `\`". Para isso eu uso a [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\\]`, que basicamente pega todos os caracteres que **não** estão entre `[^` e `]`. No caso, a `\` deve ser escrita como `\\`, pois se fosse apenas `[^\]`, o trecho `\]` seria interpretado como "o caractere `]`" ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/hhF1Wf/1/)).

E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", garantindo assim que deve ter pelo menos um caractere.

A regex também usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que a string só pode ter o que está na regex.

O método [`IsMatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8) retorna um booleano indicando se a string corresponde à regex.

---

Vi que você usa `ToUpper()` no seu código, então se quiser que a regex seja *case insensitive*, basta usar a [`RegexOptions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.8) correspondente:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[^\\]+\\Rem\\[^\\]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Assim, o nome do diretório pode ser `rem`, `Rem`, `REM`, ou qualquer outra combinação entre maiúsculas e minúsculas, que a regex dará o *match*.

---

Se quiser pegar o nome do arquivo (sem os nomes das pastas), basta colocar o trecho correspondente entre parênteses:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[^\\]+\\Rem\\([^\\]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = regex.Match(@"Cliente1\REM\COB0111111.REM.txt");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Repare que no último trecho foram adicionados parênteses: `([^\\]+)`. Eles formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e isso torna possível recuperar o trecho correspondente da string.

Como é o primeiro grupo de captura (pois é o primeiro par de parênteses que aparece na regex), podemos recuperá-lo através de `match.Groups[1]`, sendo que o `match` foi retornado pelo método [`Match`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8).

No código acima, será impresso "COB0111111.REM.txt". Adaptando para o seu exemplo (no qual há uma lista de nomes), poderia ser assim:

```
List<string> nomes = ....
List<string> nomesValidos = new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[^\\]+\\Rem\\([^\\]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (string nome in nomes)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(nome);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        nomesValidos.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
        // ou Add(nome), se quiser o nome completo do arquivo
    }
}
```

<sup>*[Exemplo no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/hPlUwX)*</sup>

---

Se as entradas são controladas e você sabe que só receberá nomes de arquivos, acredito que isso seja suficiente. O problema é que `[^\\]` significa "qualquer caractere que não seja `\`", então vai aceitar qualquer um mesmo (inclusive caracteres especiais, quebras de linha, etc), podendo aceitar strings que não são necessariamente nomes de arquivos e diretórios ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/cB2LJR/1/)). Mas se você sabe que esses casos não ocorrem, tudo bem usá-la.

Se quiser, pode ser mais restritivo. Por exemplo, em vez de `[^\\]`, poderia usar `[a-z0-9\.\-]+` (uma ou mais letras, números, pontos ou hífens), assim a regex só aceitaria nomes de arquivos que contém esses caracteres. Mas essa regex também tem seus problemas, pois é bem ingênua, já que aceita strings como `-----` ou `.....` ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/gWwg9q/2)).

Mas creio que para os casos apresentados, não parece valer a pena complicar tanto a regex, e as opções acima devem ser o suficiente.

---

Por fim, reforço que a sua solução com `Split` me parece ser a mais simples. Até porque [*split* e *match* são apenas dois lados da mesma moeda](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch): no *split* eu digo o que não quero que esteja no resultado final (o separador `\`), no *match* eu digo o que quero (as partes que estão entre as `\`). E muitas vezes é mais fácil definir um dos dois (no seu caso específico, o *split* eu acho mais fácil).